# Meaning of this sentence and the construction "but besides that"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I understand to the first comma, but I cannot understand the rest.

> You may need to change some habits and expectations, **but besides that** I do not see any reason why you wouldn’t benefit from reading this book if your goal is to make games with this tool.

How can I interpret it? 
I think that the following part may be the reason I  don't understand the whole meaning.

> but besides that

Thanks!

Comment: When you are [asking a question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it is always good to include your own attempts to solve the problem. E.g. if you have looked up '[besides](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/besides)' in a dictionary, you should write that in your question and add why the definitions you found don't help.

Comment: _but apart from that_...  (NOT _in addition to that..._)

Comment: @Lucky Thank you! I will try to write more information that you mentioned like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is written somewhat clumsily. But here's what it means:

> 1. In order to learn to make games with this tool …
> 2. You may need to change some habits and expectations (that you acquired from experience with other tools).
> 3. That (need to change habits and expectations) is a reason why you might not benefit from reading this book.
> 4. But, I do not see **any additional reasons** why you would not benefit from reading this book.

In the sentence, "**besides that**" means "other than the (possible) need to change habits and expectations". The word "**that**" refers to the need to change habits and expectations. The word "**besides**" means "other than, apart from, in addition to".

Here's why the writing is clumsy. The fact that you may need to change habits and expectations is a very weak reason to think that you wouldn't benefit from reading the book. If I understand it correctly, the need to change habits and expectations results from the nature of the tool, not from the book. So, the meaning of "besides that" is a little hard to figure out. To figure it out, you need to understand that the sentence is talking about reasons why you wouldn't benefit from reading the book, which doesn't come until later. Also, the sentence actually gives another reason why you might not benefit from reading the book: if your goal is *not* to make games using the tool!

It would be simpler and clearer to write:

> As you learn to use this tool to make games, you will likely need to change some old habits and expectations.

and then explain something about that change in habits and expectations. It might be even clearer to omit the sentence altogether. There's no need to suggest that the reader wouldn't benefit from reading the book.

Comment: Thank you for your simpler and clearer writing! Actually, They are parts of game development book. I always think that technical documents are written easily, but this book's author does not think like me. It is not easy for me to read this book :(